# Google play games services, unpublishing, deleting and starting over

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm working on a game for Android and unknowingly made a mistake in publishing the play game services prematurely. I've just now discovered that there are certain things that cannot be changed once published.

Amongst them are my Achievements. I would like to completely change some of them and turn them to hidden rather than shown automatically.

- What is the best way to go about this, do I need to just start a new Game Service?
- Do I also need to create a new Application?
- I cannot see any way of completely deleting the current Game Service, will that be stuck in my account forever? Any way of deleting it?

Answer (score 0):

> **IMPORTANT**:
>
> I have not actually tested going through these steps, so I am not sure
>   if it will leave you in a worst state than before. I am just guessing
>   based on the options I see available. If you try them, please let us know if it worked!

In the top right hand corner of the Game Services overview for your game, there is a drop-down likely labeled "Publish". If you click it, there is an option to "Unpublish".

[image]

I ***suspect*** that if you unpublish the game, you will get these options (which I see for games I have never published):

[image]

As you can see there is an option to "Delete Game".

Before deleting the game though, I would check if you can now change the stuff that could not be changed before. I think you might be out of luck though, and the Developer Console is constantly putting up warnings that say once you publish the game certain things cannot be changed.